# How to remove the cache of a spefic JFrog artifcact remote repository (offline mode)

Tags: artifactory

How do I remove the cache of an artifact in a remote JFrog repository (offline mode)?

Comment: I would recommend reading through [SO tour
page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to
ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I believe, if you make it Offline, you can't use the repository anymore.
If you do not want to save the artifacts in remote-cache, you can go to Admin > repositories > Remote repository > select your repository > Advanced > uncheck the checkbox "Store artifacts locally".